# Creating an object from JSON data in cell

Tags: javascript, object, google-sheets

In my Google spreadsheet, I have a cell A1 with JSON data:

```
{
  "car": 2,
  "train": 8,
  "plane": 5
}
```

In the Script editor, I have the following function `sortOrder` that is supposed to sort the data by the values in descending order and return the corresponding key of the highest number (which in this example would be `train`):

```
function sortOrder(string) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(string.responseText);
    // I tried with and without 'JSON.parse' and 'responseText' too

    let maxKey = Object.keys(obj)[0]
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      if (obj[key] > obj[maxKey]) {
        maxKey = key
      }
    }

    return maxKey

}
```

But this only works when I set `obj` within the function like this:

```
var obj = {
      "car": 2,
      "train": 8,
      "plane": 5
}
```

Instead, I need to have the object as a parameter of the function. There seems to be something wrong with how the cell content is being treated by the function.

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: What does ````string.responseText```` print? Is it undefined?

Comment: `function sortOrder(string) { return string.responseText }` leaves the cell blank with no error message. If I just add `var obj = JSON.parse(string.responseText);` I get an error message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 (line 2).`, line 2 being the line I declared the variable `obj`.

Comment: The stated error message means JSON.parse is not necessary. So string.responseText is probably an object. Does your string.responseText depend upon in any API call or promise based method?

Comment: I took away `JSON.parse`. Now `var obj = string.responseText;` returns the error message `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object (line 20).`, line 20 being `let maxKey = Object.keys(obj)[0]`. I'm not sure I understand your question but the JSON data is just text manually added into the cell. **Edit:** When I set `var obj = string;` and then `return obj[maxKey]`, it returns the last character of the string (`}`). **Edit:** I made it work! `var obj = JSON.parse(string);` which I swear I had tried before? I'm so sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `var obj = string` returns the last character of the string `}`, then try using

`var obj = JSON.parse(string);`

instead

`var obj = JSON.parse(string.responseText);`.

It will convert your JSON string to an object.